# What is the purpose of Content-Type at response header?

Tags: node.js, express, content-type

```js
const binary = xxxxx;
res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');
res.send(binary);
```

The above is sample on returning an image, defining on express route. What I don't understand is that despite I change `Content-Type` to `application/json`, it seems to work too?

```js
const binary = xxxxx;
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); //Still returning an image?
res.send(binary);
```

Comment: The header is just a *suggestion* to the browser what to read it as. That doesn't mean the browser will follow that suggestion - if there is a mismatch between what the browser expects and gets, it could very well try to determine what the actual type is from the information received. Some times browser will flat out ignore the content types - too many times you get servers that are misconfigured in some way and either don't return a content type or return the wrong one.

Comment: @VLAZ: In other words, there isn't really a concrete reason to set a `Content-Type` since browser has rights to disrespect the value?

Comment: Sort of. It's a historical reason boiling down to *because* many servers were either not giving the content type or missing it entirely, browsers had to do their own fingerprinting. Which in turn makes the content type header optional, since the browsers will do it *anyway*. Which means that more servers are free to miss it or misconfigure it...you get the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Content-Type` header merely indicates the media type of the resource. Browsers can use MIME sniffing and completely ignore it in some cases. To prevent this behaviour, you can set `X-Content-Type-Options` to `nosniff`.

A question arises: do I even need to set this entity header? Without setting it you force browsers to sniff the MIME type every single time and thus potentially interpret and display the response body as a content type other than the intended one. If your server allows the user to upload files, a hacker can carry out an XSS  attack by manipulating the content in a way to be accepted by the web application and rendered as HTML by the browser. He can inject code in e.g. an image file and make the victim execute it by viewing the image.